# jNetPcap for Android Packet capture

Tags: android, networking, android-wifi, jnetpcap

I have been trying to capture the packets in my android app when connected to Wifi.

I am using a broadcast receiver class.

I have successfully received the broadcast when connected to a wifi network, using this code:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (null != activeNetwork) {
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
                //wificonnected
                return 1;
            }
}
```

I want to capture the packets when network connected. I know everything about wifiInfo and WifiManager class.

I am trying here with **jNetPcap** library. How to capture those packets? I have no ideas.

Please help me guys...

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use VpnService to redirect all of your device's network traffic through your app.

If you want to use jNetPcap, [here's a working example](http://sourceforge.net/projects/prueba-android/) (more info [here](http://jnetpcap.com/node/792) and [here](http://jnetpcap.com/userguide/android)).

After reading your traffic, you'll have to open one socket to each destination port/ip as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162069/sending-a-raw-packet-to-a-networkinterface-in-android-doesnt-work/15440263#15440263). It won't be easy, though. You'll have to understand VpnService first, I suggest you take a look at ToyVpn as a start.

Hope this info helps.