# How to modify AOSP to capture network Traffic

Tags: android-source, android-networking, packet-capture, android-network-security-config

I want to modify AOSP to capture the network traffic and file operation behavior of APPs installed on my ROM. 
I have installed the rom to my nexus_6p. 
I don`t know how to modify AOSP to capture(OR log) the network traffic cause i am not very well in android development.
Please tell me where or how to modify it. If there is any article, you can also post it. Thank you

I am **not** a malicious developer , this is just my project which detects suspicious apk and this project Will not be made public.

**Thanks again!**

Answer (score 1):

No need to modify the AOSP source, you can run an app that will do this. Android has a mechanism for routing traffic to an app called VpnService (it's not actually a vpn).

There are apps that already do this, for example [tPacketCapture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture).

If you're interested in developing such an app yourself, you may find these questions of interest:

[Android VpnService, packets forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910082/android-vpnservice-packets-forwarding/23744701)

[Sending a raw packet to a NetworkInterface in Android doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162069/sending-a-raw-packet-to-a-networkinterface-in-android-doesnt-work/15440263)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by modifying the AOSP.

You have to do something to these following components which produce network traffic.

- OkHttpRequest
- Webview.apk

If you need any further help, I would attach here detailed technical tips or step-by-step manual.